# get the day of the year as an integer in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin

I am trying to get the current day of the year as an integer to access within my program. I looked at the Kotlin Docs and found a function called `getDay()`, but when I type it into my program it gives me an error and says the function is not defined. I am using Android Studio with Kotlin and the minimum API is 21.

[image: IDE code Error]

Comment: sounds like you are looking for someone to do your home work...

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note: If you want to work with a specific timezone, use LocalDate.now(ZoneId)
        // e.g. LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane")) or
        // LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) etc.
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        int doy = today.getDayOfYear();
        System.out.println(doy);

        // Using DateTimeFormatter (not recommended for production code)
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("D", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDoy = today.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(strDoy);
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone, Europe/London:**

```
289
289
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PO8ftI)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

## For any reason, if you want to use the legacy API:

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
```

***Let's see why knowing the above fact is important:***

The function, [`Calendar#getInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--) returns a calendar based on the current time in the default time zone with the default [FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.Category.html#FORMAT) locale. If you want to find some information from it for some other timezone, you have two options:

1. Change the default timezone e.g. `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Brisbane"))`. However, this may result in other parts of the application behave incorrectly. Therefore, **this option is strongly discouraged**.
2. Format the `java.util.Date` (which you can get via [`Calendar#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--)) using `SimpleDateFormat` set with the required timezone shown above.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("D");

        // For the JVM's timezone
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(sdf.format(now));

        // For the timezone, UTC
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(now));

        // For the timezone, Australia/Brisbane
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Brisbane"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(now));

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone, Europe/London at the time of posting this answer:**

```
289
289
290
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/T1Zg7B)

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you perform [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) in order to be able to use `Java 8 Time API` back to API 21, you can then use this method to get the day of year

```
import java.time.LocalDate

val dayOfYear = LocalDate.now().dayOfYear
System.out.println(dayOfYear);
```

Answer: 289

Answer (score 2):

`Date().getDay()` or rather `Date().day` in Kotlin returns the day of the week so not what you want.

`Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` is the correct function to use in Android. It returns a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default FORMAT locale (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--).

`Calendar`, `Date` etc. have been replaced by new `java.time` classes with Java 8 so you should use `LocalDate.now().dayOfYear` but as @nuhkoca indicates in order to do that you need to enable Java 8+ API desugaring support which is basically adding this to your build file (Kotlin DSL not Groovy):

```
compileOptions {
   isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.util.*




fun main() {

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val day = cal[Calendar.DATE]
    val doy = cal[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR]

    println("Current Date: " + cal.time)
    println("Day         : $day")

    println("Day of Year : $doy")
}
```